# Python converting dictionary to dataframe and exporting it to a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary to a dataframe and then exporting it to a csv file but for some reason when the program exports the dataframe it changes the columns and rows.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
for i in range(len(df['name'])):
    names.append(df['name'][i])
    balances.append(df['balance'][i])





def acc_creation(name):
    names.append(name)
    dict = {'name': names, 'balance': balances}
    new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        dict, orient='index', columns=['name', 'balance'])
    new_df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=',',
                  header=False, na_rep=0, index=True)
```

then it stops working and this is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darkmbs/Desktop/python/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    balances.append(df['balance'][i])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'balance'
```

the output I want:

```
name,balance
xyzz,0 
abc,0
```

the output I get:

```
name,xyzz,abcd   
balance,0,0
```

Comment: Why use `pandas` at all?

Comment: Anyway, don't use `orient='index` and don't use `header=False`.  Please in the future, provide a [mcve]. Most of this code is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: when i don't use `orient='index'` I get this error: `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: OK, so then they have to be the same length. You *definitely* don't want `orient='index'`, do you understand what that does? That is doing exactly what you *don't* want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is `names` and `balances` have different lengths. When you call `acc_creation(name)` you add an extra element to `names` (`names.append(name)`), but not to `balance`, so there is a length mismatch. Something you could do is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def acc_creation(name):
    names.append(name)
    balances.append(0) # Or any value
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([names, balances]), 
                                   columns=['name', 'balance'])
    new_df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=',',
                  header=True, na_rep=0, index=True)
```

Comment: yea I fixed that  but by your method, it got rid of 'name' and 'balance' fom the csv file

Comment: @BilalSohail you mean that 'name' and 'balance' column names doesn't appear in the csv file?

Comment: @BilalSohail ok then change: header=False to True from new_df.to_csv(...). Check update

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just remove:

```
 orient='index',
```

If you are getting that error message, let us see some of the original csv so we can test it and understand why.

Comment: when I remove `orient='index' `I get this error: `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: print the dict and post it here please

Comment: `{'name': ['xyz', 'abc', 'ma'], 'balance': [0, 0, 0]}`